# Why does this code give me the incorrect answer?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm attempting to write a program that uses an lcg as a function to calculate more random numbers using the box muller algorithm. I have gotten the lcg to work but the function that uses the box muller algorithm is giving out the wrong values.

Here's my code:

```
module rng
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
  real(kind=dp) :: A=100, B= 104001, M = 714025

contains

function lcg(seed)

  integer, optional, intent(in) :: seed
  real(kind=dp) :: x = 0, lcg

  if(present(seed)) x = seed
  x = mod(A * x + B, M)
  lcg = x/714025

end function


function muller(seed)
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
  integer, optional, intent(in) :: seed
  real(kind = dp) :: y1, y2, mean = 0.49, sd = 0.5, muller1, muller2, 
muller, x1, x2, pi = 4.0*ATAN(1.0)
  integer :: N  = 0

! I had to add the do while loop to ensure that this chunk of code would 
only execute once  

do while (N<1)

  x1 = lcg()
  x2 = lcg()
  N = N + 1
  y1 = sd * SQRT(-2.0*LOG(x1)) * COS(2*pi*(x2)) + mean
  y2 = sd * SQRT(-2.0*LOG(x1)) * SIN(2*pi*(x2)) + mean

  print *, y1, y2, x1, x2  ! Printing x1 and x2 to allow me to use a 
calculator to check program is working correctly
end do

end function

end module

program lcgtest
  use rng
  implicit none
  integer :: N

  real(kind=dp) :: lcgmean, ttl = 0, sumof, lcgvar, dev1, muller1, muller2, 
lcgerr, lcgdev
  real, dimension(10000) :: array


 do N = 1, 10000

  ttl = ttl + lcg()
  dev1 = lcg() - lcgmean
  sumof = sumof + dev1  

end do
  muller1 = muller()
  muller2 = muller()
  lcgmean = ttl/10000
  lcgvar = ((sumof)**2)/10000
  lcgdev = SQRT((sumof)**2)/10000
  lcgerr = lcgdev/100
  print *, lcg(), "mean=", lcgmean, "variance=", lcgvar, lcgerr


end program
```

The key part is the muller function section. After checking the values I get with a calculator, I can see that the answers for y1 and y2 are different.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Which answer does it give? Which answer do you expect? Why?

Comment: `y1` and `y2` are local variables and you don't assign to the function result.  That's an answer, but I'm not sure it's a helpful one: you seem to be missing a lot of fundamental understanding of how functions work.  Can you present a simpler problem?

Comment: Curious, why didn't you do `double(kind=dp), parameter :: pi = 4.0*ATAN(1.0)` in the module level so it doesn't get re-calculated every time?

Comment: @ja72 It isn't recomputed every time, it is a saved variable. A (possibly global) constant would be better though...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're expecting as result from this program. However, read it it I can easily get the logic you followed. I notice two factual errors. Please, read through the code below to see my enhancement.

```
module rng
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
    real(kind=dp) :: A=100, B= 104001, M = 714025

contains

    function lcg(seed)

        integer, optional, intent(in) :: seed
        real(kind=dp) :: x = 0, lcg

        if(present(seed)) x = seed
        x = mod(A * x + B, M)
        lcg = x/714025

    end function lcg ! Note 'lcg' here @ the end 


    function muller(seed)
        integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
        integer, optional, intent(in) :: seed
        real(kind = dp) :: y1, y2, mean = 0.49, sd = 0.5, muller1, & 
                           muller2, muller, x1, x2, pi = 4.0*ATAN(1.0)
        integer :: N  = 0

        ! I had to add the do while loop to ensure that this chunk
        ! of code would only execute once  

        do while (N<1)
            x1 = lcg()
            x2 = lcg()
            N = N + 1
            y1 = sd * SQRT(-2.0*LOG(x1)) * COS(2*pi*(x2)) + mean
            y2 = sd * SQRT(-2.0*LOG(x1)) * SIN(2*pi*(x2)) + mean

            ! Printing x1 and x2 to allow me to use a 
            ! calculator to check program is working correctly
            print *, y1, y2, x1, x2  
        enddo
    end function muller ! note the function name @ the end here

end module rng ! Note 'rng' here added.

program lcgtest
    use rng
    implicit none
    integer :: N

    real(kind=dp) :: lcgmean, ttl = 0, sumof, lcgvar, dev1, muller1, &
                     muller2, lcgerr, lcgdev
    real, dimension(10000) :: array


    ! In the original code the variables  'lcgmean' and 'dev1' were      
    ! *undefined* before they were used in the do-loop. This will cause the   
    ! compiler to set them some random garbage values, and it will 
    ! inevitably leads to unexpected result or error in most cases.

    ! In, order to avoid this by setting them.
    ! For example, lcgmean = 1.0 and dev1 = 0.1
    ! We'll then have the following:
    lcgmean = 1.0
    dev1 = 0.1
    do N = 1, 10000
        ttl = ttl + lcg()
        dev1 = lcg() - lcgmean
        sumof = sumof + dev1  
    end do

    muller1 = muller()
    muller2 = muller()
    lcgmean = ttl/10000
    lcgvar = ((sumof)**2)/10000
    lcgdev = SQRT((sumof)**2)/10000
    lcgerr = lcgdev/100
    print *, lcg(), "mean=", lcgmean, "variance=", lcgvar, lcgerr

end program
```

**Additional suggestions**

I find it often very useful to always close your block-of-code meaningfully like this (for example):

```
real function func_name(arg1, arg2, ....)
    implicit none

     ....
end function func_name

subroutine sub_name(arg1, arg2, ...)
    implicit none

    ...
end subroutine sub_name
```

Remark: The variable `seed` is unused in the function `muller`. Maybe it is not needed.

Comment: Note that this is still not valid code: the function result is not defined during execution of the function `muller`.

Comment: And the problem is pretty big if the OP has really problems with using functions correctly.

Comment: Thanks @fracescalus for your point.  I am going to provide one alternative in an answer below.

Comment: @eapetcho At least a note that the function does not return anything should really be edited into this answer, otherwise it is crucially incomplete.

Comment: @Vladimir F. Please have a look at my new improved code below where I think I addressed this.

Comment: That is a new answer, but please [edit] this answer, just a small note is enough. It is OK to post multiple answers, if they are different solutions to the problem but I think it is important to say that the function does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Given what I read [here](http://www.design.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/Gaussian.html), it seems that it is better to replace **function muller** by a **subroutine** so that it can calculate simultaneously **y1** and **y2**. In fact, the "block" *muller" purpose is to generate two other pseudo-random numbers based on two previously generated pseudo-random numbers *x1* and *x2* according to *your* program structure.

Then in the main program, instead of calling  **muller** as a *function*, you should call it as subroutine by writing **call muller** at the corresponding position. However, the use of *function* rather than *subroutine* is still possible, but to return the two values **y1** and **y2**, you can return a vector v, such that v(1) = y1; v(2) = y2.

The original program will become the following:

```
module rng
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)
    real(kind=dp) :: A=100, B= 104001, M = 714025

contains

    function lcg(seed)
        implicit none    
        integer, optional, intent(in) :: seed
        real(kind=dp) :: x = 0, lcg

        if(present(seed)) x = seed
        x = mod(A * x + B, M)
        lcg = x/714025

    end function lcg ! Note 'lcg' here @ the end 

    !-------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! Subroutine muller.
    ! Here, we supply 4 arguments *y1, y2* and the optional 
    ! argaument *seed* which apparently is not required since it is not
    ! used (but can be used in order to have a better pseudo number     
    ! generator.
    !-------------------------------------------------------------------
    subroutine muller(y1, y2, seed)
        implicit none
        real(kind=dp), intent(out)     :: y1, y2
        integer, optional, intent(in)  :: seed

        ! Local variables
        real(kind=dp)                  :: x1, x2
        real(kind=dp)                  :: mean = 0.49, sd = 0.5 
        real(kind=dp)                  :: pi = 4.0*ATAN(1.0)
        integer                        :: N  = 0

        ! The **do while** loop is not needed
        ! do while (N<1)
        x1 = lcg()
        x2 = lcg()
        N = N + 1
        y1 = sd * SQRT(-2.0*LOG(x1)) * COS(2*pi*(x2)) + mean
        y2 = sd * SQRT(-2.0*LOG(x1)) * SIN(2*pi*(x2)) + mean

        ! display to the screen the values of x1, x2, y1, y2
        print *, y1, y2, x1, x2  
        ! enddo
    end subroutine muller
end module rng

program lcgtest
    use rng
    implicit none
    integer :: N
    real(kind=dp) :: lcgmean, ttl = 0, sumof, lcgvar, dev1
    real(kind=dp) :: lcgerr, lcgdev

    ! Because the variable **array** is not used, I will comment it out
    !real, dimension(10000) :: array
    real(kind=dp) :: out_lcg

    ! In the original code the variables  'lcgmean' and 'dev1' were      
    ! *undefined* before they were used in the do-loop. This will cause the   
    ! compiler to set them some random garbage values, and it will 
    ! inevitably leads to unexpected result or error in most cases.

    ! In, order to avoid this by setting them.
    ! For example, lcgmean = 1.0 and dev1 = 0.1
    ! We'll then have the following:
    lcgmean = 1.0
    dev1 = 0.1
    ! The above is true for the variables **sumof**
    sumof = 0.0
    do N = 1, 10000
        ttl = ttl + lcg()
        dev1 = lcg() - lcgmean
        sumof = sumof + dev1  
    enddo


   call muller(y1, y2)
   call muller(y1, y2)
   lcgmean = ttl/10000
   lcgvar = ((sumof)**2)/10000
   lcgdev = SQRT((sumof)**2)/10000
   lcgerr = lcgdev/100
   out_lcg = lcg()
   print *, out_lcg, "mean=", lcgmean, "variance=", lcgvar, lcgerr

end program
```

I'm convinced that the program above is far from doing what you want exactly. But it solves the issue you encountered.

**Notes**:
I supplied *y1* and *y2* to the **subroutine muller** because I imagine that you probably want to access the new generated pseudo-radom number. Also, I saw a lot of room where the variable *array* could be used. Finally, maybe it's advisable to check your algorithm and the calculation carried out in the last stage for **lcgmean, lcgvar, lcgdev** and **lcgerr** and see how you can incorporrate the use of **array** and whether this alternative is more *efficient* and *faster*